# Nuget package references cause "Could not load file or assembly" ？

Tags: c#, nuget

There is a recent principle on Nuget package parsing. For details, see how NuGet parses package dependencies. A Microsoft diagram is used to explain:

[image: Microsoft Image]
This time you will choose the most recent package, which is the 2.0 version. 
no problem.

One problem I encountered today is that one of my Nuget packages (called Package A current version 1.2.3) originally only supports the version of netstandard 2.0, which is defined in the csproj file.

`<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`

I have another product, the ECS Nuget package (called Package B version 1.0.0), and Package B needs to reference Package A.

The relationship route is [Package B 1.0.0] -> [Package A 1.2.3]

At this time, the two packages in the program can be used normally.

Later, due to the support of the .net framework, I modified the original package A nuget package and changed it to the following.

`<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45</TargetFrameworks>`

Package A package generation version is 1.3.2. At this time, I refer to the above two packages and find that the compilation is ok, but I am getting an error at runtime.

[image]
I can solve the above problem by upgrading Package B, but why is this error? 
Is it because of the use of TargetFrameworks? 
I also hope that the big men will give pointers.

Comment: Which program are you using too reference the library? Is it using `PackageReference`? do you see a build warning in VS about needing to add binding redirects to app.config?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I create a netcoreapp2.0 console application to test this scenario. It is using PackageReference and there is no build warning.

Comment: @doublnt i think the error may caused by different version of packages, set same version number for two packages in config file                             <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: @MathanKumar Set the same version can be solve the problem, however, i want to know more detail about how? and why?

Comment: install the same version package to both project or set the version number you installed in the startup project file and also referenced project like this                                            <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

Answer (score 0):

When I compare the `*.deps.json` file, I found something helpful. Here is the first scenario get the following json file:
[image: Fisrt]

```
"aliyun-net-sdk-core/1.3.2": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Serilog": "2.5.0",
          "Serilog.Exceptions": "4.0.0",
          "Serilog.Sinks.File": "4.0.0"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/aliyun-net-sdk-core.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "0.0.0.0",
            "fileVersion": "0.0.0.0"
          }
        }
      }
```

Because of the reference to version 1.3.2, however, the CLR can't find the DLL with Version 1.3.2 when loading the assembly, there is only assembly version 0.0.0.0, so the CLR looks for the 1.2.3 version referenced by the original project, but it is not found, so it reports an error. 
Clearly understood.

After I make up the miss assembly version of the project, I got the 
right result.

[image: Second]